# How to use testnet during development in Coinbase Wallet

Tags: ethereum, web3js, coinbase-api, ethers.js

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I've searched around and have found no obvious way to select an Ethereum testnet while developing an application to support Coinbase Wallet. Am I missing something obvious or is only Mainnet supported? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is something I wanted to find out myself and found a solution for both the mobile and the desktop chrome wallet.

on the Desktop Coinbase Wallet you can switch to a testnet with below steps:

- Open the settings from the top right
- Enable the Developer Mode checkbox
- In settings under 'Default Network' you can now find a section with multiple testnets

For the coinbase mobile wallet:

- Open Settings in the bottom right
- Open Advanced Settins
- Switch Network from Mainnet to Testnet
- Go back to settings and choose testnet under 'Default Network' setting

In both examples I am referring to the non-custodial wallets from Coinbase, not the managed custodial wallet apps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Most mobile wallets do not support testnets.

[For different wallets, check this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82532/620). For mobile wallets supporting testnet, ask help in [WalletConnect Discord](https://walletconnect.com/).